# chef server unable to add run list - Unsatisfiable run list item

Tags: chef-infra

So I'm new to Chef. I've created a cookbook and tested it with Kitchen,Vagrant and Virtual Box and all works well. I've now installed Chef Server and bootstrapped a node that I would like to run my cookbook against. I've used knife to upload the cookbook to the chef server. So far all good.

Now when I go to add an item to the nodes run list, I get the error:

```
Unsatisfiable run list item
```

followed by:

```
Unable to satisfy constraints on package apt, which does not exist, 
due to solution constraint (jenkins_server >= 0.0.0).
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: You cookbook depends on `jenkins_server` cookbook which seems to not be present on the chef-server, upload it also. Have a look at `knife upload --help` to find the parameter to upload dependencies at the same time as your cookbook.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I'm still confused. jenkins_server is the name of the cookbook that I'm trying to use in the run list. It exists on the server along with all the recipe's etc.

Comment: Sorry, the missing one is `apt`: "Unable to satisfy constraints on package apt, which does not exist". the message sounds strange that said, I had though it was cookbook and not package.

Comment: Following on from your comment though, I did some more digging into the dependent cookbooks and they don't exist on the server. I tried knife upload jenkins_server --include-dependencies but knife couldn't find the dependent cookbooks even though they exist on my workstation in ~/.berkshelf/cookbooks. I tried adding ~/.berkshelf/cookbooks to the knife.rb config but still no luck.

Eventually, I tried manually copying the dependent cookbooks to the same cookbook folder as jenkins_server and it worked. That can't be the correct solution though.

Comment: If you're using Berkshire,berks upload would upload the dependencies properly

Comment: Thanks. berks upload worked but I had to add the --no-ssl-verify flag

Comment: Well, get your server cert, append it to chef cacert.pem and export an environment variable `SSL_CERT_FILE` pointing to it and it should work.